# Modify a file content in C# using the Stream's API

Tags: c#, file, stream

I have a .json file who handles the user's roles and I have wrote a Repository who's responsible of adding/removing roles to users. The pb is that when I modify the file I want to be sure that no one access it except me.

Here's (roughly) the code I use:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_rolesFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
{
    var oldContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    var contentObject = Deserialize(oldContent);

    Modify(contentObject)

    var newContent = Serialize(contentObject);

    fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    streamWriter.Write(newContent);
}
```

The pb with this solution is that if `newContent` is a string shorter that `oldContent` some characters will be remaining in the file.

A solution I found is to add the following code:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_rolesFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
{
    //...

    var newContent = Serialize(contentObject);
    var endPosition = fileStream.Position;

    fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    streamWriter.Write(newContent);
    streamWriter.Flush();

    while (fileStream.Position < endPosition)
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine();
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }
}
```

It works well but does not look very clean to me. Are there any better solution who ensure that I keep the control of the file ?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: I wouldn't say it is not clean. I think this code is quiet good. But if you want another  solution, you can delete the file and create a new one with the same name. Then you are sure that only your text is in the file.

Comment: @Presi - delete/create can be "racy" since there's no way to keep a "lock" on the name between those two steps. Truncating all/part of a file is a well known operation and the "challenge" is working out how it's exposed in .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `fileStream.SetLength(fileStream.Position)` to *truncate* the remaining part of the file. This assumes that the `FileStream` is left correctly positioned by the `StreamWriter` after use, but that's an assumption your current code seems to be making too.

(This is a safer assumption than the corresponding usage of `StreamReader` where internal buffering may mean that the underlying stream's position is further advanced than the latest data returned by a call to a `Read` method)

Comment: Thanks ! Would that be the final code: `fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
streamWriter.Write(newContent);
streamWriter.Flush();
fileStream.SetLength(fileStream.Position);` ?

Comment: May it be simplified to this code: `fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                fileStream.SetLength(0);
                streamWriter.Write(newContent);` ?